# Math.Trunc function reducing the value by 0.001

Tags: javascript, math, truncate, tofixed

```html
<div id="demo1"></div>
<div id="demo2"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = (Math.trunc(1005)/1000).toFixed(3);
</script>
 
<!-- *The above usage gives the value as* **1.005** -->

<script>
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = (Math.trunc(1.005*1000)/1000).toFixed(3);
</script>

<!-- *The next usage gives the value as* **1.004** -->

<script>
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = (Math.trunc(1.004*1000)/1000).toFixed(3);
</script>

<!-- *The next usage gives the value again as* **1.004** -->
```

Why is this happening?

Since I am using Math.Trunc(), it should render same values after using toFixed() function but its value is getting reduced.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKpHT.png)

Answer (score 1):

**First Script**: `(Math.trunc(1005)/1000).toFixed(3)`

- `Math.trunc(1005)` simply truncates the number 1005, which remains 1005.
- Then, you divide 1005 by 1000, resulting in `1.005`.
- `toFixed(3)` correctly formats this as `"1.005"`.

**Second Script**: `(Math.trunc(1.005*1000)/1000).toFixed(3)`

- `1.005 * 1000` in JavaScript doesn't exactly equal 1005 due to floating-point precision errors. Instead, it results in something slightly less, like `1004.9999999999999`.
- `Math.trunc(1004.9999999999999)` then truncates this to `1004`.
- Dividing 1004 by 1000 gives `1.004`.
- `toFixed(3)` correctly formats this as `"1.004"`.

Comment: Third Script: (Math.trunc(1.004*1000)/1000).toFixed(3))
1.004 * 1000 in JavaScript return 1004, and hence this works fine! Got the logic! Thanks!

Comment: How to avoid this and get expected outcome? Any method?